# Crystal reports - Can't filter on custom formula number field

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal reports don't let me use a custom count formula field to filter which transactions to show in a manager report.

I'm creating a Crystal report that team leaders are supposed to take out to see on how many occasions their employees have reported in sick. A record is only supposed to show if that person has reported in sick 6 or more times the last 12 months.

The report shows a record (a page) for each employee belonging to the managers organisational unit. Below the employee information is a subreport where I show the transactions from the salary/time system. Using select expert, I have filtered out the transactions that is supposed to show. I have then created a database field that count which day was 12 months back from today, and filtered so that only the transactions falling into this period shows.

My last problem is that I only want to show the record that has a minimum of 6 such transactions during the period. I created a formula field named @Antal ("amount" in Swedish) that simply counts the distinct number of dates in the "from"-date for the salary transactions I'm showing (since a change of law 2019-01-01 we needed to create a new transaction type, so some of the occasions after 2019 may have two transactions referring to one sick leave, thus I'm counting the first day of the period instead), `DistinctCount ({P_LSTAT.P_SXXX06})`

Now, the subreport has a new column with Antal (amount) that counts the amount of the desired salary transaction. I then try to use the selection formula to only show records where `{@Antal} >= 6` but I get the following error:

> This formula cannot be used because it must be evaluated later

Is there any other (better) way of doing this, or am I simply missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your selection based on {@Antal} >= 6 you need to use the group selection formula, not the record selection formula.  Record selection is used to select records which meet the criteria before reading in the data. Group selection is used to filter out entire groups of records based on summarised values, after the records have been read in and the summaries calculated - which sounds like exactly what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a Formula Field is out of scope when the Select Expert is evaluated.

There is no process for calculating the value of a Formula Field before it is printed within the section of the report it is placed.  The Select Expert is evaluated prior to any section of the report being printed, so at this time all Formula Fields are effectively Nothing.